# How to switch between two identical EDMX files at compile-time?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

EDIT: The **primary question** is "*is it possible to control "Build Actions" of individual CS files from the Configuration Manager?*". Eg, I change from "Debug" to "Release" and file1.cs and file2.cs change from Action "Compile" to Action "None" for example.

[image: vis]

OLD POST:
I'm in a bit of an unusual situation where I have two EDMX files in the same assembly. Each one is pointing to the same database, and has the same namespace/classes/etc although one is a Sql Server edmx and the other is a Postgres edmx, but everything else is identical.

Without going into a huge explanation for why these need to be in the same assembly, is there a way to define some compile switches for the Solution or Project file so that I can enable only one EDMX at a time?

It seems like I can set the Build Action of the 2nd EDMX (and all its generated CS files)  from "EntityDeploy"/"Compile" to "None".

Then if I need to run the 2nd one, I have to switch the process - disabling the 1st EDMX but I'm having to do this all manually. It would be optimal if there was a way I could create a build (like debug/release) but something like "1st_EDMX_Debug", "2nd_EDMX_Debug", "1st_EDMX_Release", "1st_EDMX_Debug".

As a side bonus, it would also be good if there was a way to create these "Build Switches" to include new table CS files created later like if the database is modified.

Comment: The only possibility I see is to edit the t4 templates and add `#if` compiler directives on top of each entity class and the context class.

Comment: Thanks Gert, yeah I can't seem to find a way to do it short of what you've suggested.